# In Sharepoint2007 survey, I need to show Question3 only if Question1 AND Question2=Yes

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, branch, survey

I need to create a survey on a Sharepoint 2007 site.  In this survey I need to:

(a) Ask everyone Question1 and Question2
(b) Show Question3 ONLY IF Question1=Yes AND Question2=Yes

Comment: If Colin's answer worked for you then click the big tick icon next to it and mark it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

IT's not possible, there is a workaround though. You create the first question, this is a branching question. Then you add two question that are the same, but one is for the "Yes" branch of question1, 1 is for the "No" Branch of Question1.

-The Question2 you added under the "Yes" Branch of Question1 is also a branching question, the "Yes" branch goes to Question3, the "No" branch closed the survey.
-The Question2 you added under the "No" branch of Question1 is a regular question, that closes the survey.

so you get

```
Question1 - No  - Question2 (regular) - No  - END
                                      - Yes - END

          - Yes - Question2 (Branch)  - No  - END
                                      - Yes - Question3 - No  - END
                                                        - Yes - END
```

Here's an explanation about branching logic

[explanation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA102090651033.aspx)